# Find the limit of $\frac {x^2+x} {x^2-x-2}$ where $x \to -1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limit of $\frac {x^2+x} {x^2-x-2}$ where $x \to -1$. Right now I am getting $\frac{0}{0}$ if I don't factor first, or $\frac{2}{0}$ if I do.

Here are my factoring steps:

$\frac {x^2+x} {x^2-x-2}$

$=\frac{x(x+1)}{(x-2)(x+1)}$

*replace $x$ with $-1$*

$=\frac{-1(-1+1)}{(-1-2)(-1+1)}$

$=\frac{2}{-3 (0)}$

$=\frac{2}{0}$

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When you plug in $x = -1$ after factoring you still get $0/0$. You made a small error.

Comment: @angryavian I see it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x^2+x}{x^2-x-2}=\frac{x(x+1)}{(x-2)(x+1)}=\frac x{x-2}\xrightarrow[x\to-1]{}\frac{-1}{-3}=\frac13$$

The above is justified by the fact that taking the limit when $\;x\to-1\;$ means $\;x\;$ gets closer and closer to $\;-1\;$ **but never equals it** in this limit process.

To calculate a limit as $\;x\to a\;$  is the same as substituting $\;x=a\;$ in the function *iff* the function is continuous at $\;a\;$ , otherwise it may fail...as in this case, where the function's not even defined at $\;x=-1\;$

Answer (score 1):

You can't plug it in since the function $f(x) = {x^2+x\over x^2-x-2}$ is not continuous at $x=-1$.

You have to cancel it first by $x+1$, then you can plug it in.

Answer (score 0):

Just factorise:

$$\frac{x^2+x}{x^2-x-2} \equiv \frac{x(x+1)}{(x-2)(x+1)}$$

Assuming $x \neq -1$, we can divide the numerator and denominator by $x+1$. For all $x \neq -1$, we have

$$\frac{x^2+x}{x^2-x-2} = \frac{x}{x-2}$$

As $x \to -1$, we see that 
$$\frac{x^2+x}{x^2-x-2} \to \frac{-1}{-1-2} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

In your approach, you noticed that the function you are taking the limit of is effectively $f(x)=\frac{x}{x-2}$ but undefined at $x=-1$. It IS however, defined all the way up to $-1$, so you can take the limit of this $f$, which is simply $f(-1)$

Answer (score 0):

In addition to factoring to solve this problem, you can also use L'Hôpital's rule because when plugging $x=-1$ directly into the function gives you $\frac 00$.

Take derivative of top and bottom to get $\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}$ and then plug in $x=-1$ to get $\frac{-1}{-3}=\frac 13 $

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
x^2-x-2
&=x^2-2x\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-2\\
&=\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2\cdot4}{4}\\
&=\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{9}{4}\\
&=\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\\
&=\left(x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right)\\
&=(x-2)(x+1)
\end{align}
$$

Now, things are going to cancel out nicely:

$$
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -1}\frac {x^2+x} {x^2-x-2}=
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -1}\frac {x(x+1)} {(x-2)(x+1)}=
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -1}\frac {x} {x-2}=\frac{-1}{-1-2}=\frac{-1}{-3}=\frac{1}{3}.
$$

Comment: Did it really take you $6$ lines to show that $x^2-x-2=(x+1)(x-2)$?! Just use $$a+b=-1; ab=-2$$ to get $a=1, b=-2$, then its $(x+a)(x+b)$...

Comment: The process I used is called completing the square. I think that for somebody who is not as proficient at math, it's good to use something simpler. However, I absolutely don't have anything against the way you do things.

Comment: @MikeR. I think that for beginners using the method proposed by Rhys, which in fact is just Viete's formula from high school, is way simpler and easier than what you showed...which is certainly completing the square but made long and slightly messy.

Comment: @MikeR. Completing the square *IS* a rather simple concept, however, it is much quicker and simpler to use the formula I explain in my answer. It may even be faster to drag the results from the Quadratic Equation than completing the square. In general, we normally see CTS used for "Prove $f(x)>0$ questions, as it does this very nicely, but for factorisation it is clunky and inefficient, as shown by your taking six lines to show it.